# Maven Dependency Plugin go-offline not downloading some plugins

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to download all transitive dependencies and plugins for a pom file into a local folder and then using it to run sonarqube offline. I am fairly new to Maven, so I might be doing something wrong here, but I think maven maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:go-offline is not downloading all plugins needed to run sonarqube, which is causing an error.

This is what I have tried.

1. Download all dependcies to a new folder

`mvn -D"maven.repo.local"="c:\test\test" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:go-offline`

2. run sonar

`mvn -o -D"maven.repo.local"="c:\test\test" sonar:sonar`

This however gives me the following error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 has not been downloaded from it before.
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5 has not been downloaded from it before.
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8 has not been downloaded from it before.
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.5.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.5.3 has not been downloaded from it before.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.133 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-30T14:35:43+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (c:\test\test), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

The POM file is as below

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld_Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Since it is complaining about various plugins not being available, I gather there is a problem with the maven-dependency-plugin not downloading all necessary plugins needed to run sonarqube ? Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Is the sonar plugin defined in the POM?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have attached the POM also.

Comment: You have an unusual use of quotation marks around your parameters. I don't know whether is this a real issue, though. Furthermore, have you checked the contents of c:\test\test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sonar-maven-plugin` should be declared as a plugin and not as a dependency.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: One more question. Do you know if it would be possible to download all required dependencies for sonarqube programmatically via maven-resolver ?

I tried changing 
`https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java`
but it doesn't download any of the plugins.